# How to Add “Enabled Globally” in each entry page?

Tags: craft3

I want to Add "Enabled Globally" in each entry page So when users create a new page, it will set **English as the default content (apply to other languages),** then the user can edit on specific language.

The options given in the screenshot are my requirement

[image]

Comment: What is stopping you from doing that? What is the specific problem you're encountering? What have you tried?

Comment: I have a multi-language site I want to add "Enabled Globally" option on each entry page when I create a new page and save the page after fillup content for the English language then it will apply to other language if I check/enable "Enabled Globally"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple sites, the `...` button beside “Enabled for [Site Name]” will expand the setting so you can toggle the status for each site, including a switch for toggling the entry’s global status.

[image: The initial state of an entry’s status setting, showing a single switch input for the current site, plus an ellipsis button, which has been emphasized by a red circle around it.]

[image: The entry’s status setting once the ellipsis button has been pressed, showing that it now contains three switches: one for the global status, and one for each of the entry’s two sites. The global status switch has been emphasized by a red circle around it.]

Comment: But for a single page when I am data entry for the English language, other languages are not being applied.

Comment: By “single page” do you mean an entry within a “Single” section?

Comment: Yes, single section

Comment: Go to your Single section’s settings and make sure it is enabled for multiple sites. Then the entry’s Enabled setting will look like my screenshots.